# In python opencv, why is array[:] and array different?

Tags: python, arrays, opencv

I'm a python and opencv newbie so bear with me if simple question.

In the code below, how come the 2 array calculations provide different answer?

> (a) channel[:] = channel * normalizedInverseAlpha
>   (b) channel = channel * normalizedInverseAlpha

How come (a) and (b) are the not the same?

```
normalizedInverseAlpha = (1.0 / 255) * (255 - graySrc)
channels = cv2.split(src)
for channel in channels:
    channel[:] = channel * normalizedInverseAlpha
    #this is different from channel = channel * normalizedInverseAlpha. Why?

cv2.merge(channels, dst)
```

Comment: provide output of both the cases.

Comment: [No "_I'm a newbie_" please.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `[:]` to do array slice-op for every element in the array.

> (1)

```
for channel in channels: 
   channel[:] = channel * alpha
```

Assign the result of `channel * alpha` to `original channel`.

> (2)

```
for channel in channels: 
    channel = channel * alpha
```

Create a new variable named channel and assign the result of `channel * alpha` to `new channel`, has no effect on the original.

---

Here I do an experiment:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018.01.20 19:28:35 CST
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("test.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

alpha = (1.0 / 255) * (255 - gray)

channels = cv2.split(img)

for channel in channels:
    print("Before:", id(channel), channel.shape, channel.dtype)
    channel[:] = channel * alpha
    print("After:", id(channel), channel.shape, channel.dtype)

dst1 = cv2.merge(channels)


channels = cv2.split(img)
for channel in channels:
    print("Before:", id(channel), channel.shape, channel.dtype)
    channel = channel * alpha
    print("After:", id(channel), channel.shape, channel.dtype)

dst2 = cv2.merge(channels)

dst2 = cv2.merge(channels)
cv2.imshow("dst1", dst1)
cv2.imshow("dst2", dst2)
cv2.waitKey()
```

---

The output:

```
Before: 140130414391088 (480, 480) uint8
After: 140130414391088 (480, 480) uint8
Before: 140130413969616 (480, 480) uint8
After: 140130413969616 (480, 480) uint8
Before: 140130413969776 (480, 480) uint8
After: 140130413969776 (480, 480) uint8
Before: 140130413969936 (480, 480) uint8
After: 140130414391088 (480, 480) float64
Before: 140130413970016 (480, 480) uint8
After: 140130414391088 (480, 480) float64
Before: 140130413970096 (480, 480) uint8
After: 140130414391088 (480, 480) float64
```

We can clearly see the `id of channel keeps the same` then do `channel[:] = channel * alpha`, so assign on the `original channel`; while `id changes` when doing `channel = channel * alpha`, so assign on the `new channel`, keep the original.

---

The result is as expected:

[image]

Comment: This is impressive! I immediately understand. I also learned new code from you. Thanks!!!  However, I find it strange that Python will create a new variable of the same name within the same statement